# What is the way to make Tune run parallel trials across multiple GPUs?

Tags: ray

I am hoping to make Tune run each trial of a grid search in parallel across multiple GPUs.  I have a 4 GPU machine with 24 VCPUs.  When I run the following code, I see 3 GPUs being used in by `nvidia-smi`, but it is only running one trial.

```
tune.run("PPO",   
            config={
                "env": "PongNoFrameskip-v4",
                "lr": tune.grid_search([0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]),
                "num_gpus": 3,
                "num_workers": 3
            }
        )
```

I can see from the run that Tune is only running one trial.

```
== Status ==
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources requested: 4/24 CPUs, 3/4 GPUs, 0.0/190.43 GiB heap, 0.0/12.84 GiB objects
Memory usage on this node: 5.4/220.4 GiB
Result logdir: /home//ray_results/PPO
Number of trials: 3 ({'RUNNING': 1, 'PENDING': 2})
PENDING trials:
 - PPO_PongNoFrameskip-v4_1_lr=0.001:   PENDING
 - PPO_PongNoFrameskip-v4_2_lr=0.0001:  PENDING
RUNNING trials:
 - PPO_PongNoFrameskip-v4_0_lr=0.01:    RUNNING
```

I tried setting `resources_per_trial` with `"gpu":1` but Ray gave an error to clear `resources_per_trial`.

```
ValueError: Resources for <class 'ray.rllib.agents.trainer_template.PPO'> have been automatically set to Resources(cpu=1, gpu=3, memory=0, object_store_memory=0, extra_cpu=3, extra_gpu=0, extra_memory=0, extra_object_store_memory=0, custom_resources={}, extra_custom_resources={}) by its `default_resource_request()` method. Please clear the `resources_per_trial` option.
```

What is the way to tell Tune to run all 3 trials in parallel?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
tune.run("PPO",   
        config={
            "env": "PongNoFrameskip-v4",
            "lr": tune.grid_search([0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]),
            "num_gpus": 1,
            "num_workers": 3
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you - just confirming that this worked.  I do have one question.  I updated the example to have 8 workers.  Now each trial says "9 CPU, 1 GPU".  Is it counting the head as 1 CPU in each trial?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.

Comment: @KeijiKanazawa You could mark the answer as expected as it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation to richiliaw's answer:

Note that the important bit in `resources_per_trial` is **per trial**. If e.g. you have 4 GPUs and your grid search has 4 combinations, you must set **1 GPU per trial** if you want the 4 of them to run in parallel.

If you set it to 4, **each trial will require 4 GPUs, i.e. only 1 trial can run at the same time**.

This is explained in the [ray tune docs](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/user-guide.html), with the following code sample:

```py
# If you have 8 GPUs, this will run 8 trials at once.
tune.run(trainable, num_samples=10, resources_per_trial={"gpu": 1})

# If you have 4 CPUs on your machine and 1 GPU, this will run 1 trial at a time.
tune.run(trainable, num_samples=10, resources_per_trial={"cpu": 2, "gpu": 1})
```